# How to detect if ListView items are enough to trigger scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, chat, listviewitem

I've having a chat app, if the `ListView` items are not enough to scroll then the row should be at the top of the list. If the items are enough to trigger scroll then the list should scroll always scroll down to show the latest conversation like in the iMessage setup.

I tried adding in the XML:

> android:stackFromBottom="true"

but this would cause the `ListView` to scroll down `ALWAYS.` I only want to scroll down if the items are enough to cause scrolling, if not then it should scroll up.

I would use this if I could detect the enabling of scroll:

```
myListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
        myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    }
});
```

So how would I detect if the `ListView` items are enough to trigger scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to detect the scrollable

```
if (yourListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == yourListView.getAdapter().getCount() -1)
{
 //It is scrolled all the way down here
}
```

to check the last visible item is still smaller the item number :)

Comment: Since I'm populating the `ListView` under the Asynctask, I placed your code block after setting my `ListView` adapter. But it doesn't seem to work, since it's a chat app I have a single `ListView` item that has many text so the height is big which triggered a scroll. I think your code block only works if the `item count` can trigger scroll, but I just realized now that even a single row can have a big height since it's a chat.

Comment: Your list view is a global variable and one item is a text view that contains your text message.
You populate your list view at first in onPreExcute() to load all previous message if had. I think that, the trigger should be applied here.

Comment: I have been populating my `ListView`s in my onPostExecute. The real problem here is that the item number is counted, but the item itself has big height so the scrolling is already triggered but still not does not match your condition.

Comment: yourListView.getChildAt(yourListView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= yourListView.getHeight()) to detect the heigh.
You should add this condition and the above condition :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by placing this code `listView.setSelection(rowAdapter.getCount());` after `listView.setAdapter(rowAdapter);`. When chat messages are only few, it is scrolled up and when the messages are enough to trigger scroll then it is scrolled to the bottom. Just like I want it.